# Linq to Sql update creates duplicate record

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm using linq to sql in my data layer where I have added a "settings" table to the regular asp_user table.
In this settings table I keep several records of which one is the prefered Unit (a foreign key to the Units table).

Now when this prefered unit needs to change (say from liter to kilogram), I do a call to my UnitService to get the correct unit instance and set my setting.PreferedUnit to this instance.
This creates a new (duplicate) item in the database (there are now two kilogram records in my Units table). This is of course not what I intended.

I have the feeling I'm doing a bunch of fundamental stuff wrong

```
UserSetting setting = AccountService.GetUserSetting(user.Identity.Name);
if (setting.PreferedUnitId != unitId)
     setting.Unit = UnitService.GetUnitById(unitId);
AccountService.SaveuserSetting(setting);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do a DataContext.Units.[Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978.aspx)(unit) to let Linq to SQL know that your unit object already exists and doesn't need to be inserted. Note that I'm assuming that your Units table is exposed as a Units property on the DataContext.

I'm speculating here, but it appears that your AccountService is using a different DataContext to your UnitService so you're actually in the disconnected objects scenario. This [blog post](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/12/LINQToSQLAttachMethodAttachingDetachedBusinessEntitiesDataContextAttach.aspx) might make things a bit clearer

Answer (score 1):

What does `AccountService.SaveuserSetting` do? It's probably doing an unnecessary `InsertOnSubmit`.

Comment: Yes, is that implicit? So what happens if I decide that my changes should be reverted and I should not commit?